# JavaFX 8 count rows in "textarea"

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, textarea

We are trying to count the number of rows in a TextArea
Here are the TextArea properties PrefWidth 600 and PrefHeight 620 with MaxHeight 620
Wrap Text is set to true. We are using JavaFX 8 with Scene Builder
We have a textPropertyListiner that will fire an Alert when the TextArea.getLength is greater than some value
The issue with this method is it does not consider the user entering a carriage return \n

So we implemented this code to capture the \n

```
    String toCount = txaDiaryEntry.getText();
    String [] lineArray = toCount.split("\n");
    int LA = lineArray.length - 1;

    if(LA == 0){
      rc = rc - 1;
      System.out.println("###### LA "+LA+" RC "+rc);
    }
```

The if test is always ZERO so this runs every time the user types anything after one carriage return is entered
This code is inside the textPropertyListiner
When the entered text does a line wrap no \n is created
We have looked at numerous old post and tried a few examples with no results
**The question is how to count rows in a TextArea that has carriage returns and line wrap is true?**
As I am testing I notice some of the issue with the posted code is that the LA value continues to increase. Because we seldom work with Array My guess is that the Array needs to be cleared when the value reaches 1
So if anyone would care to explain how to accomplish that with this String[] array we will give that a test

**We have EDITED the question code to reflect a working example of counting BOTH line wraps and when the user presses the ENTER key. While this works we might add that using Row Count to prevent further text entry is not as favorable as counting the number of characters in the TextArea.**

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
txtTitle.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black;");
getDate();

    if(doEDIT.equals("TRUE")){
       btnEdit.setVisible(true);
       btnSave.setVisible(false);
        try {
            ReadChildTable();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EnterController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    try {
        ReadParent();
    } catch (SQLException | IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EnterController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    txaDiaryEntry.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

    EC = txaDiaryEntry.getLength();
    tEC = tEC + 1;
    // this counts line wraps every 62 char
    if(tEC == 62){
        RC = RC - 1;
        tEC = 0;
    }

    // This counts ENTER key presses
    String toCount = txaDiaryEntry.getText();
    String [] lineArray = toCount.split("\n");
    LA = lineArray.length - 1;

    if(LA == tLA){
        tLA = LA + 1;
        RC = RC - 1;
    }else if(tLA < LA){
            tLA = LA + 1;
             RC = RC - (LA - 1);
    }else{  
    }

    // This test counter
    int minus = EC+(LA * 40);
    int val = 1200 - minus ;
    txtCR.setText(String.valueOf(val));
    uEC = uEC - val;

    if(LA == 0){
       uEC = 1200;
    }else{
       uEC = 960;// 880
    }

    if(EC > uEC){
    //if(RC == 0){  
        alertTYPE = "4";
        //RC = RC + 1;
        try {
            customAlert();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EnterController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        txaDiaryEntry.requestFocus();
    }     
    });     
}
```

Please see comments in the code as this method manages other tasks.

Comment: May be i am a bit confused.. so is it that you want the no of lines from the entered text (i.e separated by \n) or no of visible lines/rows use see in textarea (because of textwrap and \n)?

Comment: @SaiDandem We want to capture the number of \n created when the user presses ENTER and subtract from a preset RowCount we can count the number of Rows created when the use is just typing Issue is not being able to reset or clear String[ ] as stated in my Edit to the Question it keep increasing

Comment: @SaiDandem We tried this code but no luck lineArray = null

Comment: Not sure what is the exact issue. Because for me adding this code is giving me the correct count of lines. May be can you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

textArea.textProperty().addListener((obs,old,txt)->{
            System.out.println(txt.split("\n").length);
        });

Comment: @SaiDandem Added the code that does the counting commented where the code works Notice one trick every 62 characters entered we subtract from the total Entered Text to simulate a \n THIS WORKS the FAIL is with the String[ ] array

Comment: @SaiDandem Yes the code is very dirty SORRY the testing has gone crazy will give your example a test because this is the init code it runs every time some variables are declared above so as to be global Thanks

Comment: Your requirements are not completely clear. Do you want to count how many literal line separators there are, how many times the text has been wrapped on screen, or both? Note that text wrapping is purely a rendering "trick" and does not result in inserting a line separator into the text. You would have to calculate how many times a line of text would wrap based on the width of the characters and the wrapping width. The problem with that is JavaFX does not provide a public API for testing the width of a character based on its font—at least not as of JavaFX 13.

Comment: @Slaw We have now realized that text wrapping does not insert a line separator. We needed to count both and we will revise our code to reflect that we can count rows for both a full line of text that wraps and when the ENTER key is pressed. It even counts if the ENTER key is pressed multiple times Thanks for the comment

Comment: @Grendel We have been trying to deal with this question we were able to count one carriage return but not multiple \n the nested if statements or the else if did the trick. It is a shape the question was down voted as stated numerous questions with very few workable answers Good Work

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them (ReadParent seems to be a method, not a constructor - is it?).

Comment: @kleopatra we made a mistake posting our solution we used RC = RC - 1 we have corrected the POST it should have been RC = RC - (LA - 1); when the CR detects more than one CR  or \n two CR Thanks to all your replies we will work on our correct syntax skills

Answer (score 4):

As already noted by @Slaw in one of his comments, there is no *public* API to access the line count in a textArea (emphasis by me). On the other hand, there is internal API that provides what we need - if we are daring enough and allowed to work with internals.

Looking at public api and digging into the implementation details of TextAreaSkin, it turns out that (currently, up to fx13 and probably later)

- `textArea.getParagraphs()` seems to return the charSequences that are separated by a hard linebreak
- the skin merges all paragraphs into a single text node
- text has-a textLayout field that handles the line/char layout
- textLayout provides a method `getLines()` which returns an array of textLines separated by either soft or hard linebreaks, for counting we are only interested in its length.

Below is a quick example that demonstrates how to make use of these internals. Basically, it looks up the area's text node (available after the skin is attached), reflectively accesses its textLayout and query the length of the lines array.

Note that this is for fx9+ (probabbly not much changed against fx8 except for pulling the skins into public scope, didn't check, though). To allow access to internals, we need to tweak module access restrictions at both compiletime and runtime.

Compiletime:

```
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.text=ALL_UNNAMED
```

Runtime:

```
--add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.text=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.text=ALL-UNNAMED
```

The example to play with:

```
public class TextAreaLineCount extends Application {

    String info = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. " +
            "Nam tortor felis, pulvinar in scelerisque cursus, pulvinar at ante. " +
            "Nulla consequat congue lectus in sodales.";

    private Parent createContent() {
        TextArea area = new TextArea(info);
        area.setWrapText(true);

        area.appendText("\n" + info);

        Button append = new Button("append paragraph");
        append.setOnAction(e -> {
            area.appendText("\n " + info);
            LOG.info("paragraphs: " + area.getParagraphs().size());
        });
        Button logLines = new Button("log lines");
        logLines.setOnAction(e -> {
            Text text = (Text) area.lookup(".text");
            // getTextLayout is a private method in text, have to access reflectively
            // this is my utility method, use your own :)
            TextLayout layout = (TextLayout) FXUtils.invokeGetMethodValue(Text.class, text, "getTextLayout");
            LOG.info("" + layout.getLines().length);
        });
        BorderPane content = new BorderPane(area);
        content.setBottom(new HBox(10, append, logLines));
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.setTitle(FXUtils.version());
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(TextAreaLineCount.class.getName());

}
```

Comment: Called out of town. ReadParent is a method to read from a DB not connected to the txaDiaryEntry.textProperty().addListener We are trying to capture only one \n and multiple \n to decrease RowCount (RC) as the user enters data into the txaDiaryEntery TextArea

Answer (score 2):

A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is something that can be copied and run without much changes, should also have self explanatory variables.

For your reference, I am providing a demo and can you please update it as per your requirment. It is very hard to follow your code as the variables are not explanatory.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextAreaLinesCount_Demo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setSpacing(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        final Scene sc = new Scene(root, 350, 200);
        stage.setScene(sc);
        stage.show();

        Label lines = new Label();
        Label alert = new Label();
        GridPane gp = new GridPane();
        gp.setHgap(10);
        gp.setVgap(10);
        gp.addRow(0, new Label("No of Lines:"), lines);
        gp.addRow(1, new Label("Alert:"), alert);

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setWrapText(true);
        textArea.textProperty().addListener((obs, old, text) -> {
            lines.setText(text.split("\n").length + "");
            validate(text, alert);
        });
        VBox.setVgrow(textArea, Priority.ALWAYS);
        root.getChildren().addAll(gp, textArea);

        textArea.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.");
    }

    private void validate(String text, Label alert) {
        // Can you add your logic here.. and update the "alert" label for when to show the alert
    }
}
```

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them (tongue-in-cheek <g>)

Answer (score 2):

Grendel this code seems to complicate the task of counting the \n by using the String[ ] array. This code posted below

```
    // This counts ENTER key presses
String toCount = txaDiaryEntry.getText();
String [] lineArray = toCount.split("\n");
LA = lineArray.length - 1;

if(LA == tLA){
    tLA = LA + 1;
    RC = RC - 1;
}else if(tLA < LA){
        tLA = LA + 1;
         RC = RC - 1;
}else{
```

So rather than deal with the String [ ] array here is a little less code that just counts the occurrences of \n and as your original code did it subtracts a given number of characters

```
    String toCount = txaDiaryEntry.getText();
    S = toCount.split("\n",-1).length - 1;
    RowCount = RowCount - 1;    
    // This test counter
    int minus = EC+(S * 40);
    int val = 1200 - minus ;
```

All the code to deal with the String [ ] array was clever but way crazy and hard to follow. Now you can play with the number 40 for perhaps a more realistic character count?

Comment: nope, he wasn't. textarea in word wrap mode does not insert any breaks into the data, these "soft wraps" only existing in its inner representation. So we need a dirty hack as javaFX does not let us to. Yet another hellowording framework with overoptimistic reception...