# How to count lines of a paragraphs in textArea in java?

Tags: java, javafx, count, textarea

I am working on a JavaFX project and have defined textArea within scrollPane within which text should be entered from text files of the user's choice.

I've added a counter that counts the lines inserted into the textArea:
`textArea.getText().lines().count()`
so that I can set the height of the textArea (by setting the value obtained from the counter, in the PrefRowCount parameter in textArea).

The problem is that the numerator in this way counts the **paragraphs** in textArea (according to how written in text files) and what I need is to get the number of **lines within each paragraph** as shown in my textArea (according to the font settings, font size, etc.).

And here I asked: Which way can I enumerate the lines within each of the paragraphs in textArea so that I can adjust this to the correct height that textArea should have?

My JavaFX Controller looks like this:

```
public class Controller {

    ObservableList<String> days = FXCollections.observableArrayList
            ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
            "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20",
            "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"),
            months = FXCollections.observableArrayList
            ("Tishrei", "Cheshvan", "Kislev", "Tevet", "Shevat", "Adar",
            "Nisan", "Iyar", "Sivan", "Tammuz", "Av", "Elul");

    public ComboBox day, month;
    public TextField year;
    public Button ok;
    public ScrollPane scrollPane;
    public TextArea textArea;

    @FXML
    private void initialize(){
        day.setItems(days);
        month.setItems(months);
    }

    public void okClick() throws IOException {

        String dayValue = (String) day.getValue();
        String monthValue = (String) month.getValue();

        String dayFile = ("/textFiles/days/"+dayValue+".txt");
        String monthFile = ("/textFiles/months/"+monthValue+".txt");

        InputStream inDayFile = getClass().getResourceAsStream(dayFile);
        InputStream inMonthFile = getClass().getResourceAsStream(monthFile);

        BufferedReader readerDayFile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inDayFile, "UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader readerMonthFile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inMonthFile, "UTF-8"));

        String dayTitle = ("Day " + dayValue + ":\n");
        String monthTitle = ("Month " + monthValue + ":\n");

        String scanDayFile  = new Scanner(readerDayFile).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        String scanMonthFile  = new Scanner(readerMonthFile).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

        textArea.setText(dayTitle + scanDayFile + "\n\n" + monthTitle + scanMonthFile);

        long lineCount = textArea.getText().lines().count();
        textArea.setPrefRowCount(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(lineCount)));
        scrollPane.setVvalue(0);

    }

}
```

Comment: not supported - faintly remember there was an earlier question here on SO with a workaround.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand exactly what from each the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174808/javafx-8-count-rows-in-textarea) is useful for me. Could you please specify how exactly can I incorporate this into my code? I'll be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

the line in text-area is somehow different from the line concept that you might think. In java a line is a text separated with newline or \n.

when a text can not be fitted in the text area width the remaining characters of the text string, will be moved to the next line in the text-area, but it doesn't mean that it actually is a newline. a line will be finished when Enter button is pressed or \n encountered in a string.

If you need to adjust your text-area and you read the content from a text file you might need to count the numbers of characters in the text file, find the numbers of characters that can be fitted in your text-area width, and divide number of characters by that to determine the needed height needed for your text-area.

But since the text-area is scroll-able I don't quit understand the reason behind all this trouble you are going through.